# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.compat'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, kivy

I need some help with kivy:

I had install kivy by following these steps:

PIP Commands:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle
python -m pip install pygame
python -m pip install kivy
```

When I did -m pip install kivy I had a bunch of errors so I used the github installation: git clone http://github.com/kivy/kivy-designer/

This was working for a while until another problem arose and I installed more wheels. After installing those wheels my kivy stopped working and gave this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/Mikul Vineet/Python/AutoClicker 2.0/AutoClicker.py", line 1, in <module>
     import kivy
   File "D:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
     from kivy.utils import platform
   File "D:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 26, in <module>
     from kivy.compat import string_types
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.compat'
```

The code I used was

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.app import App
```

Please help, I have tried uninstalling kivy and reinstalling but that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `pip` installed modules to the path.

Try
`pip show kivy`, note the path and then do 1 of the following:

1. Either add the path in your python file, or
2. Add the path you PATH variable.

Comment: It says WARNING: Package(s) not found: kivy

Comment: When I do python -m pip install kivy, i get an error that says - The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b) Click OK to close the application.

Comment: That means the package is not installed. Try reinstalling pip once?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue. I was naming the file as kivy.py , we cannot name the file using any library name as it treats as a package and cannot import the functions. Also, I tried using pip install kivy in cmd , the package must be installed in the Environment Variables . I was able to access it from my C: drive .
I just renamed the file as main.py and it worked !